# How to iteratively create new variables to store the ith value of a list

Tags: python, loops, lambda

I want to write a function that takes `L`, a list of tuples (an example might be `L = [(1,0,0), (1,1,0)]`), and loops through `L` to create a new variable `t{0}.format(i)` for the `i`th entry in `L`. So ideally at the end of this for loop, `t1 = (1,0,0), t2 = (1,1,0)`. And then I'm going to turn the tuples into lists, but I googled for that and found that I could just do `t1 = list(t1)`. How can I accomplish the first part though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could make global variables like this:

```
L = [(1,0,0), (1,1,0)]

def make_vars(L):
    for i, item in enumerate(L, start=1):
        globals()['t{0}'.format(i)] = item

make_vars(L)
print(t1)
# (1, 0, 0)
```

But really, what good is dynamically named variables? They are hard to program with, since you don't know their names until runtime. (You might guess (rightly or wrongly) that there is a `t1`, but is there a `t10`?)

Using a dict is much better:

```
def make_vars2(L):
    return dict(enumerate(L, start=1))

t = make_vars2(L)
print(t[1])
# (1, 0, 0)
```

With a `dict` all your "variables" are bundled together in `t`, and you know exactly what "variables" are in `t`, `t.keys()`, and they do not pollute your global namespace.

However, on second thought, do you really need a `dict` at all? Wouldn't `L` itself suffice? Accessing the items in the  `L` with `L[i]` is faster than accessing the same item with `t[i+1]`:

```
In [3]: %timeit t[1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 66.1 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit L[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 42.8 ns per loop
```

Comment: `return dict(enumerate(L, start=1))`  or even `return {i:list(v) for i, v in enumerate(L, start=1))}`

Comment: This worked great thanks. I had actually been looking into possibly doing it with `fromkeys` i.e.,: `varlist = []
>>> for i in range(4):
 varlist.append(t(i))
>>> varlist
['t0', 't1', 't2', 't3']
>>> dict.fromkeys(varlist)
{'t1': None, 't0': None, 't3': None, 't2': None}` But this works well. However, my `list` solution doesn't seem to work. Could I ask you for a tip on how to now convert a tuple like `(1,0,0,0)` into a list like `[1,0,0,0]`?

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: @JJR just use `list(your_tuple)`

Comment: @JonClements for some reason when I try to do that, it gives me a strange output: `lt = []
for key in t:
    lt.append(list(t[key]))` gives me `[[(0, 1)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7,
1)]]`